# Random sampling with sample() gives unexpected results

Tags: r, sample

Consider the following when performing random sampling in R:

```
n <- 10
k <- 10 
p <- 0.10 # proportion of the k objects to subsample
probs <- c(0.30, 0.30, 0.30, rep(0.10/7, 7)) # probabilities for each of the k objects
```

Here, the roles of n and k are irrelevant; however, there is the condition that  n >= k.

```
x <- sort(sample(k, size = ceiling(p * k), replace = FALSE)) # works
y <- sample(x, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[x]) # throws error
```

I am wondering why the function call assigned to y above throws an error.

The error I receive is:

```
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
incorrect number of probabilities
```

My thinking is that the 'size' argument to sample() (i.e., n*p) cannot evaluate to 1 in the second function call (y variable), but I haven't been able to find anything documenting this error in the help files to sample().

I know that ceiling() can act strangely in some instances, but I'm not convinced that this could be the issue.

When the above code is run, x is set to the integer data type, e.g., 1L, 2L, etc., which leads to the error in evaluating y.

Does someone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is a single value, `sample(x)` samples from values 1 through `x` (see the `Details` section of the help), or 1 through `floor(x)` if `x` isn't an integer. So the `prob` argument has to be a vector of length `x`. In your code `probs[x]` is always a vector of length 1, which causes the error.